# Do I have to add an after filter to change all response content-type to json?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm using laravel 4.2, I've recently discovered that I'm not getting 'content-type' : 'application/json' on all my API requests that are JSON.

So...

was this supposed to work out of the box or am I supposed to add a filter by myself?

my options are either changing all the responses in my code that are json to Response::json()

or

the easiest solution is adding an after filter that checks if the response is json and changes the headers

```
json_decode($response->getContent());
if ( json_last_error() == JSON_ERROR_NONE ) {
    $response->headers->set('Content-Type','application/json');
}
```

this seems to add some extra overhead for each request. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Laravel already has what you need.

`Response::json($your_data)`

read more about it in [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#special-responses)

Laravel checks if your data implement `JsonableInterface` or `ArrayObject` or it's just `array` and convert it to json and set headers.

Comment: that requires me to change all of my API responses that are right now User::find($id)->toJson() for example. Also, I need to always follow this convention and one day when I migrate to laravel I'll need to change it because laravel 5 doesn't have Response anymore.

Comment: Laravel 5 has Response, like facade and like a helper. You can omit response::json and return array laravel will convert it automatically